# Best Practice to Handle ADO.NET CRUD events

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

As you may know, when working with ADO.NET, simply put, you work with a data control and a data-source.

When handling CRUD events, mainly the Updating/Updated and the Inserting/Inserted events, you have two places to handle them: either in the control (Item_Inserted.. etc.) or in the data-source.

I tend to prefer handling such events in the data-source, because it is less frequent to change compared to the control (since you may need to change a details view to a form view when the fields number increase) especially the hidden fields appending to the data-source, because the user is not entering them, rather they are automatically generated, such as the *record date*:

```
protected void ods_ID_Inserting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceMethodEventArgs e)
{
    //Append the hidden values:
    e.InputParameters["Rdate"] = DateTime.Now;
    e.InputParameters["Creator"] = User.Identity.Name;
}
```

but today I encountered a case that made me handle it in the control level, which is keeping the control in the Insert mode when a DB error occur:

```
protected void fvw_ItemInserted(object sender, FormViewInsertedEventArgs e)
{
    //handle DB exception if any:
    if (e.Exception != null)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScript", Commons.Get_Script(e.Exception.InnerException.Message), true);
        e.ExceptionHandled = true;
        e.KeepInInsertMode = true; /*** This is not available in the data-source ***/
        return;
    }
}
```

which renders the question:

---

**Where are the best places to handle the CRUD events (mainly: Updating, Updated, Inserting, Inserted)? in the control or in the data-source?** (an explanation would be highly appreciated).

---

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

for me i also handle the crud operation in data-source because in controls u may have old values. it is better to perform crud operation using trans commit and roll back. further there is less effort in crud in data source than in frontend